# How to Avoid multiple call to method while using terneary operator

Tags: c#

in the following code snippet as you can see i need fetch value twice and then call int.parse twice , is their any way to make this better .

**I have already tried using a separate variable,but i don't want to use a separate variable and write if for same because, i have to do this many time for different configuration entities , any suggestion to write this in better way.**

`var x =int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]) == 0 ? 60 : int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]);`

Comment: Follow the answers here.  Bite the bullet and write it for each configuration entry.  The code looks so much cleaner.

Comment: What's the reason to don't use a variable?

Comment: because, i(he) have to do this many time for different configuration entities

Comment: Use unique names for variable based on the name in the config: `pollInterval` or `tmpPollInterval` or `cfgPollInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lots of calls, use a function:

```
private int GetInt(string what, int defaultValue) {
    int value;
    int.TryParse(licenseConfig[what], out value);
    return value == 0 ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int val = GetInt("pollInterval", 60);
```

You may provide `licenseConfig` with the function call:

```
private int GetInt(Dictionary<string, int> licenseConfig, string what, int default)
```

Answer (score 3):

create a seperate variable and assign the value to it.

```
int parsedValue = int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]);
var x =parsedValue == 0 ? 60 : parsedValue;
```

Though i would do it like this

```
int parsedValue;
if(int.TryParse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"],out parsedValue))
{
     var x =parsedValue == 0 ? 60 : parsedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize one variable and use same in terneary operation which make `licenseConfig["pollInterval"]` call only onces like this:

```
int _pollInterval = int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]);
var x = _pollInterval == 0 ? 60 : _pollInterval ;
```

**EDIT**

```
int _pollInterval;
int x = default(int);

if(int.TryParse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"],out _pollInterval))
    x = _pollInterval;
```

**2nd EDIT**

```
string _confiSetting = /*Here you configuration setting*/
int _pollInterval;
int x = default(int);

if(int.TryParse(licenseConfig[_confiSetting ],out _pollInterval))
    x = _pollInterval;
```

Comment: doh... you were quicker :-)

Comment: as i mentioned i dont want to use _pollInterval variable

Comment: @ankush what that means? then from where you are going to check value in terneary operation?

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]);
var x = y == 0 ? 60 : y;
```

Comment: as i mentioned  i dont want to use y variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var x =int.Parse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"]);' Get the value to x.
x=(x == 0 ? 60 : x); ' Re assign that value based on the condition
```

Not using any extra variable here.

Comment: So `x` is no extra variable?

Comment: @joe check the second comment of the answer by Anksuh. The questioner says that he doesn't needs to use any new variable. x is already in the question. Here we are using only one variable. Hope you are clear.

Comment: @venerik    int a = 1;
            a = a == 0 ? 60 : a; the value of a will be re-assigned.

Comment: @joe i dont know what is his exact requirement, as per his comments he doesn't needs any extra variable.Let us wait for the questioners review about my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int parsedValue;
int.TryParse(licenseConfig["pollInterval"], out parsedValue) ? parsedValue : 60;
```